Ballberring magnetism to create perpetual motion
Several things I'd like to get debunked:

The idea that you can use a ball bearing with magnets attached (e.g a fidget spinner with magnets with a rudimentary glue job on it) And angle magnets separate from the ball bearing device just enough to where the bearing would spin automatically from the push and the pull of the outer magnets does not work. There are videos on the internet that say it is possible to either get (or at the very least keep) a magnet spinning based on the force of the magnet. I understand that it can't last forever, but I'd like to see the math proving it/ and other factors not considered with this idea. Should it work, is it possible that the magnets can "demagnify" to the point where they don't perpetuate any magnetic force?
Could the heat generated to the magnets increase to the point where they do not function anymore?


There's no need to do any math, you just need to take into account that magnets will eventually get demagnetised due to the increase in entropy and therefore they will stop acting on the spinner, which will cease its movement.

Right, I want to disprove the "Free energy" advocates, and I am want to find some equations to disprove them
